# How to check an iOS app store receipt against a specific device?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

According to WWDC 2013 workshop 308 on validating app purchase receipts locally, one should verify:

1. That it is signed by Apple, so that it hasn't been modified
2. That it is for the same bundle identifier (app) and version of the currently running app
3. That it is associated with the current device (i.e. so that one user doesn't extract the purchase receipt and share it with others)

How is it possible to check the third item? According to the slides, one should check the device identifier hash, which on iOS is the vendor identifier. I know how to get the vendor identifier, by calling `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`. However, how do I compare this with the appropriate data in the receipt? In [Apple's Receipt Validation Programming Guide,](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) they don't list any fields in the receipt which seem to line up with the device ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at that Apple document, you'll find a chapter **Implementation tips**. Code there shows that you need to concatenate several pieces of data, generate a SHA1 hash and compare it with the one included in the receipt.

If you implementing server side validation, you may use [that tip I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295195/how-to-check-the-uid-hash-of-an-apple-appreceipt-server-side-in-php/24295196#24295196).